# Adding thick colored border to Plotly choropleth in python

Tags: python, plotly

I want to make a choropleth map in python plotly of all the U.S. states that shows the "2020 Per Capita Biodiesel Consuption" and adds a red thick border around states in the list that meet a certain condition in my data frame. How would I do that? Here is my code thus far. It generates the map I want just have no idea how to add the thicker colored borders around certain states.

```
fig_consump_percap = px.choropleth(DF,
                    locations='State', 
                    locationmode="USA-states", 
                    scope="usa",
                    color='2020 Per Capita BD Consumption (gal/person)',
                    color_continuous_scale="algae", 
                    
                    )
fig_consump_percap.show()

fig_consump_percap.update_layout(
      title_text = '2020 Per Capita Biodiesel Consumption by State',
      title_font_family="Times New Roman",
      title_font_size = 22,
      title_font_color="black", 
      title_x=0.45,
    margin={"r":50,"t":50,"l":50,"b":50},
    legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=0.5,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.5
))
```

I have tried searching documentation and other forums to see if there's a solution but haven't had much luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about this: https://community.plotly.com/t/in-choropleth-how-to-create-outline-for-country-and-differentiate-that-particular-countries-states/67013/4 ?

It is for India, but the process should be the same for the US sub-national boundaries.